# Pyside2/6 QColumnView seems broken, same model works on QTreeView

Tags: python, qt, model, lazy-loading, pyside

I'm developing an application that involves displaying a hierarchical structure of entities. These entities are stored in a large database that cannot be fetched in its entirety, so I'm implementing lazy loading, which means the entities are queried only when a user expands a parent item.

The issue I'm encountering is that when I click on an entity, I can see it being loaded in the console, but the UI doesn't update until I click on another item and then return to the original one. Interestingly, when I replace QColumnView with a QTreeView, everything works as expected.

I suspect that this might be a bug in either PySide or Qt in general. However, I'm open to the possibility that I might be overlooking something. I've attempted to emit different signals to indicate that I've updated the region, but none of my attempts have been successful. My code is currently using PySide2, but I've also tested it with PySide6 (by simply replacing the imports and exec_() with exec()), and the issue persists. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

--EDIT--

The reason I am implementing loading in this manner, as opposed to how the DirPathModel handles it, is because I specifically want to load only the entities I click on, rather than loading all visible entities.

[DirPathModel example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32506002/5954416)

--END-OF-EDIT--

My code:

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

import logging
import time
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union, Any, List

import PySide2.QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import QModelIndex, Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QColumnView, QApplication


class DatabaseConnector:
    """This queries database for projects and entities"""

    def get_root_data(self) -> List[dict]:
        time.sleep(1)  # Emulate query to server, it takes time
        return [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "type": "Project",
                "name": "Some project1"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "type": "Project",
                "name": "Some project2"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "type": "Project",
                "name": "Some project3"
            },
        ]

    def expand(self, f_id: str, f_type: str) -> List[dict]:
        time.sleep(1)  # Emulate query to server, it takes time
        # Normally this would not return get_root_data, but for simplicity of example it does.
        return self.get_root_data()


@dataclass
class Entity:
    id: str
    type: str


class BaseModel(QStandardItemModel):
    """Base model for entity selector"""

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.data_provider = DatabaseConnector()
        root_data = self.data_provider.get_root_data()
        for data in root_data:
            project_item = self._create_child(data)
            self.invisibleRootItem().appendRow(project_item)

    def _create_child(self, data) -> QStandardItem:
        """Creates a child item with a "Loading..." child."""
        entity = Entity(data['id'], data['type'])
        child_item = QStandardItem()
        child_item.setText(data['name'])
        child_item.setData(entity, Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole)

        # placeholder child because if child_item is not empty a call to data() will be made
        loading_child = QStandardItem()
        loading_child.setText("Loading...")
        child_item.appendRow(loading_child)

        return child_item

    def data(self, index: Union[PySide2.QtCore.QModelIndex, PySide2.QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex],
             role: int = ...) -> Any:

        data = super().data(index, role)
        # We catch the placeholder "Loading..." child, which means we have to
        #  populate the parent entity.
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole and data == "Loading...":
            parent_index = index.parent()
            if not parent_index.isValid():
                return data

            logging.warning("Filling")
            self._fill_parent(parent_index)

        return data

    def _fill_parent(self, parent: QModelIndex) -> None:
        """Fills the parent entity with children"""
        parent_item = self.itemFromIndex(parent)
        entity: Entity = parent_item.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole)

        # Remove the placeholder
        while parent_item.rowCount() > 0:
            parent_item.removeRow(0)

        # Ask the server for children
        children_data = self.data_provider.expand(entity.id, entity.type)
        print("Data from server", children_data)

        # Insert the children
        for child in children_data:
            print(f"Appending {child['name']}")
            child_item = self._create_child(child)
            parent_item.appendRow(child_item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    model = BaseModel()
    entity_selector = QColumnView()
    entity_selector.setModel(model)
    entity_selector.resize(800, 200)
    entity_selector.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: You should not remove items while they're being accessed by the view: when `data()` is called, the view is still expecting results from it, but you're actually destroying the index in the meantime. If you change to `QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self._fill_parent(parent_index))`, it works as expected. Still, this isn't very acceptable, as the UI should never block: a proper implementation should use a worker QThread that will query the server when the parent is showing its contents (unless the query has already been made), returning the result through a signal that will finally fill the model.

Comment: In addition to removing items, don't insert or update the data of the model inside the ```QStandardItemModel::data()```. Even though it may work currently, it may be broken in the future.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a method to determine if a user has clicked an item (indicating their intention to expand it) without relying on extra signals and `QStandardItemModel::data()`? This way, the programmer can simply call view.setModel() without any additional steps.